# Transform fields before publishing to client in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a quiz app in Meteor.

I have fields `correctAnswers` and `wrongAnswers`.

Is it possible to publish correct answers and wrong answers in a shuffled array to the client?

Right now, the user can just open his console and type `Questions.find().fetch()` and see the correct answers.

An alternative would of course be to store all answers (both wrong and correct) in an array and keep the index of correct answers in another field, which is not populated to the client, but I rather want a more intuitive data structure.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "in a shuffled array to the client". Maybe showing an example document and what you'd like it transformed to would help. It may be that a transform isn't what you want, but seeing some data would help in making that determination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two publications on the same collection: one which only publishes the questions without answers and another that publishes the answers to already answered questions. Meteor will union these data on the client so that you can query the collection consistently but essentially you have to defer the pushing of the answers to the client.

```
Meteor.publish('questionsOnly',function(){
  return Questions.find({},{fields: {questionText: 1}});
});

Meteor.publish('answersOnly',function(answeredQuestions){
  return Questions.find({_id: {$in: answeredQuestions}},{fields: {correctAnswers: 1, wrongAnswers: 1}});
});
```